# Stack images dynamically in SCSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I would like to create the following layout in SCSS: 
[image]

Due to the fact that the images have a dynamic number, it can be 4,5 or 2 images I can't hardcode the negative top or `translateY` property. So I need a `foreach` loop in SCSS so I can assign different tops to these images. Is it possible to create such a layout in SCSS or would I need to use JS?

This is what I currently have, as you can see I can move only the 2nd element, the 3rd needs already `translateY(-100%)`

```css
.layers__img {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
.layers__img:not(:first-child) {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="layers">
            <div class="layers__img" id="layer-1">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
        </div>
            <div class="layers__img" id="layer-2">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
        </div>
            <div class="layers__img" id="layer-3">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: SASS knows simple “for” loops, yes - if that’s your actual question … http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

Comment: (For anything else, you would first of all need to show us some sample code, of how _you_ want to achieve this kind of layout.)

Comment: I think jquery is better than SCSS in this case, show me your code.

Comment: @Ivan I added the code inside the question

Comment: Switching the translate for a negative margin could perhaps already achieve what you want; but if you need the stacking order with the last image on the bottom and the first one on top, you’d need to vary the z-index of the elements as well, so that would mean some sort of loop necessary again. (Unless you were willing to reverse the order of the elements in the source code, and then use flexbox order to reverse that again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below :

```js
let layers = $('.layers__img');
$.each( layers, function( key, value ) {
  var percent = 50;
  if(key != 0) {
    $('img',value).css('transform', 'translateY(-'+percent * key+'%)');
  }
});
```

```css
.layers__img {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
.layers__img:not(:first-child) {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layers">
        <div class="layers__img" id="layer-1">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="layers__img" id="layer-2">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"  width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="layers__img" id="layer-3">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"  width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="layers__img" id="layer-3">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"  width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="layers__img" id="layer-3">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"  width="100px">
        </div>
 </div>
```